# ColdFusion9: Using serializeJson on Hibernate entity encodes numeric properties as strings

Tags: json, hibernate, serialization, coldfusion

I'm writing my first ORM-backed REST api, and having some issues with the JSON serialization. Here's one of my entity definitions:

```
component persistent="true" extends="Base" {

    property name="id"
             fieldtype="id"
             generator="native"
             ormtype="int"
             type="numeric";

    property name="relationship"
             type="string"
             ormtype="string";

    property name="comment"
             type="string"
             ormtype="text";

    //related entities
    property name="termA"
             cfc="term"
             fieldtype="many-to-one"
             fkcolumn="termA"
             lazy="false";

    property name="termB"
             cfc="term"
             fieldtype="many-to-one"
             fkcolumn="termB"
             lazy="false";

    //override getMemento to include appropriate relationships
    public struct function getMemento(){
        //standard stuff
        local.memento = super.getMemento();

        //custom add-ons
        local.memento["termA"] = this.getTermA().getId();
        local.memento["termB"] = this.getTermB().getId();

        return local.memento;
    }

}
```

This is the Base entity it extends (for super.getMemento among other things):

```
component extends="core.v1.models.Base" {

    public struct function getMemento(){
        local.memento = deserializeJson(serializeJson(this));
        //fix numerics showing up as strings
        if (structKeyExists(local.memento, "id")){
            local.memento.id = javacast("int", local.memento.id);
        }
        return local.memento;
    }

    public array function transformCollectionIntoMementos(array input){
        if (arrayLen(arguments.input) > 0){
            for (var i = 1; i <= arrayLen(arguments.input); i++){
                arraySet(arguments.input,i,i,arguments.input[i].getMemento());
            }
        }
        return arguments.input;
    }
}
```

The class that *this* one extends isn't relevant here.

Finally, here's a simplified version of the code that renders the json representation of the data:

```
<cfoutput>#serializeJson(transform(entityLoad("interaction")))#</cfoutput>

public array function transform(array input){
    if (arrayLen(arguments.input) > 0){
        for (var i = 1; i <= arrayLen(arguments.input); i++){
            arraySet(arguments.input,i,i,arguments.input[i].getMemento());
        }
    }
    return arguments.input;
}
```

You can see in the `getMemento()` implementation in the 2nd code snippet that I'm attempting to resolve this by javacasting the value of all ID properties (each entity has a property named "id") to an integer. This doesn't work. I've also tried `javacast("int", local.memento.id * 1);` and that doesn't work either.

No matter what I've tried, the resulting json looks like this:

```
[{"termB":"2","termA":"1","id":"1","relationship":"+"},{"termB":"4","termA":"1","id":"3","relationship":"-"}]
```

What I'm expecting is this:

```
[{"termB":"2","termA":"1","id":1,"relationship":"+"},{"termB":"4","termA":"1","id":3,"relationship":"-"}]
```

I'm at a loss. What am I missing? Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it the change that Adobe made to serializeJSON?

http://coldfusion.tcs.de/adobe-please-fix-coldfusion-serializejson/

Comment: Indeed; and switching to JSONUtil (http://jsonutil.riaforge.org/) for the serialization fixed it straight away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this: http://jsonutil.riaforge.org/ It solved my problems with integers being converted to strings.